# Code for "Left Backslash" Key

Tags: application-development

I am redefining the keyboard layout (in a symbol file) and cannot find the name of the "**left backslash**" key (available on 102 keys keyboards, usually to the left of the **Z** key or the **space** key).

Answer (score 1):

To get it straight:

- This is a backslash: \
- This is a slash: /

They are named accordingly in the Xmodmap files.

If in doubt, run the `xev` program from the console and read its output.

Comment: In a 102 keys keyboards there are two keys with the "\" sign. You find it in most laptops and in a few desktop keyboards. On my system it produces the "less than" character.
Difference in Xev output:
Left backslash key: keycode 94
Right backslash key: keycode 51

Comment: xev should also output their names. But try this on a terminal:

`sudo dumpkeys --long-info|grep -e slash -e 33 -e 5b`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer.

- The key name is LSGT.